# Use Fubini in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, how can I justify that

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \left( \int_{x}^{b} g(y)dy\right)dx = \int_{a}^{b} g(y) \left( \int_{a}^{y} f(x)dx\right)dy  $$

using Fubini theorem (with lebesgue measure).
I can't consider the intervals $[a,b]$ and $[x,b]$ because $x$ varies in $[a,b]$. I  tried to put the domain:

$$ \{  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert a \leq x \leq y \leq b \}$$

as union of rectangles but could not

Comment: Hint: $\int_x^b g(t)dt = \int_a^b g(t) \cdot \chi_{[x,b]}(t)dt$. Now apply Fubini.

Answer (score 2):

I have learned on [this note of Donald Knuth](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9205211.pdf) that it is best to write the integration bounds as functions. We have the double integral
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \left( \int_{x}^{b} g(y)dy\right)dx.$$
In this form, manipulating it can be troublesome. But we can rewrite it as
$$
\int_{[a, b]^2} f(x)g(y)\mathbf 1_{\{x\le y\}}\,dxdy,$$
where $\mathbf 1_{\{x\le y\}}$ is the function of $x$ and $y$ that equals $1$ if $x\le y$ and $0$ otherwise. We can mechanically rewrite this integral as
$$
\int_a^b g(y)\left(\int_a^b f(x)\mathbf 1_{\{x\le y\}}\, dx\right)\, dy, $$
and now it is obvious that it equals
$$\int_a^b g(y)\left(\int_a^y f(x)\, dx\right)\, dy,$$
as expected.

(In the linked note, Knuth goes as far as suppressing the $\mathbf 1$ altogether, writing $[x\le y]$ instead. This he calls a *Iverson bracket*. I think it is a great notation, but it is not that widespread).