# Why does $\int_0^\infty\int_0^x |f''(y)| dydx = \int_0^\infty |f''(y)| y dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose I have a function $f$ which is absolutely continuous and so is its derivative. Additionally we assume that $f(0)=0$. Why does the following equality hold

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^x |f''(y)| dydx = \int_0^\infty |f''(y)| y dy$$

It seems to be a change of order of integration. Given the result it must hold

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^x |f''(y)| dydx = \int_0^\infty |f''(y)|\int_0^y  dxdy$$

but I can't see why. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3827309/8157) should answer your question.

Comment: What is $\int_0^y dx$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro's answer for the first question is really good. As far as the second, it's pretty trivial by fundamental theorem of calculus (the antiderivative of dx is just x, so the integral from 0 to y of dx is just $x_{=y} - x_{=0} = y$)

Answer (score 0):

The purported identity in the headline does not seem to hold, in general.  Let $f$ be a smooth, nontrivial function supported on $[0,1]$.  Then the integral on the right-hand side is the integral of a continuous function on the compact interval $[0,1]$ and is therefore finite.  For each value of $x \geq 1$, the inner integral on the left-hand side is the same strictly positive quantity $\int_0^1|f''(y)|\,dy$, so the outer integral will be infinite.